# Fatal error: Uncaught yii\base\InvalidConfigException: The "id" configuration for the Application is required

Tags: php, yii2

web.php

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'application',
    'name'=>'basic',
    'version' => '1.15.2',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'defaultRoute' => 'dashboard/index',
    'timeZone' => 'UTC',
    'language' => 'en-US',
    'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',
    'aliases' => [
        '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
        '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
    ],
```

index.php

```
    require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
    require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
    $config = require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/yiisoft/vendor/stevenmaguire/oauth2-keycloak/examples/index.php');
    //$config = require(__DIR__ . '/config/web.php');
    //$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php');
    (new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

index.php  for stevenmaguire plugins :

```
//require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require '/opt/lampp/htdocs/app/vendor/yiisoft/vendor/autoload.php';
//require '../../../../../../opt/lampp/htdocs/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';
//require '../../../../../../../../../../opt/lampp/htdocs/app/config/web.php';



session_start();

$provider = new Stevenmaguire\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Keycloak([
    'authServerUrl' => 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
    'realm' => 'cyber',
    'clientId' => 'client',
    'clientSecret' => '**********',
    'redirectUri' => 'http://localhost/application',
    'encryptionAlgorithm' => 'RS256', //optional
    'encryptionKey' => null, //optional
    'encryptionKeyPath' => null     //optional
        ]);


if (!isset($_GET['code']) || !isset($_SESSION['oauth2state'])) {
    // If we don't have an authorization code then get one
    $authUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl();
    $_SESSION['oauth2state'] = $provider->getState();
    header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
    exit;

// Check given state against previously stored one to mitigate CSRF attack
} elseif (empty($_GET['state']) || ($_GET['state'] !== $_SESSION['oauth2state'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['oauth2state']);
    exit('Invalid state, make sure HTTP sessions are enabled.');
} else {
    // Try to get an access token (using the authorization coe grant)
    try {
        $token = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
            'code' => $_GET['code']
        ]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        exit('Failed to get access token: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    // Optional: Now you have a token you can look up a users profile data
    try {

        // We got an access token, let's now get the user's details
        $user = $provider->getResourceOwner($token);
        // Use these details to create a new profile
        printf('Hello %s<br>', $user->getName());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        exit('Failed to get resource owner: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
//    session_write_close();

    // Use this to interact with an API on the users behalf
//    echo $token->getToken();
}
```

my question is that when i am creating realm first it go to keycloak login and redirecting to our application index.php and come to its regular flow this is i am expecting .it is login to keycloak but at time of redirecting it gives above error.how do i solve this error.....

Comment: Why you post `web.php`, when actually loading a whole different file as `$config`? It's rather unclear what the actual question is; to me this seems to be quite a self-fabricated issue. Whatever you may load into the variable, there is quite likely no `$config['id']` present. Why not just extend the `$config`?

Comment: how can extend the $config?

Comment: Why are you trying to use as config something that clearly isn't application's config array?

Comment: i have remove $config in front of require path and keep it for web.php file but error still same ,please suggest any solution

Answer (score 0):

You have your configuration in `web/` and your other one in `vendor/`, if you want to use both of them you can use array_merge by using `array_merge($config1,$config2)`, so you take everything from $config1 and replace the same with content from $config2.

in your index.php

```
$config1 = require(__DIR__ . '/config/web.php');
$config2 = require(__DIR__ . '/vend.... );

$completeConfig = array_merge($config1,$config2);
(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

i hope that can help you, correct me if i missed something.

[array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: This solution will work for 2 configs but it won't work in this case. What OP is loading as config is not an Yii's app config. It's some file containing example of usage of independent library.

Comment: thank you Kekstington sir but it shows error array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, int given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/app/index.php on line 30

Comment: that means, the 2nd parameter is a int, and not an array, but as mentioned by @MichalHynčica is my solution not the best for ur special problem

Comment: yes as per @michal hyncica

Comment: provide the right way to solve this issue please ||||